# stutter every 500 ms using nvidia-driver

Tags: xorg, nvidia, graphics

I wanted to use ubuntu with the nvidia driver on my new computer but as soon as I start to use the proprietary nvidia driver everything on the screen freeze very briefly every 500 ms. I noticed when I switch to tty that the command line is flickering.

Nb : I used this graphics card for a while with pop os and after an update (or something else) this issue appeared.

**My config :**

> CPU : Ryzen 7 2700x
>
> GPU : GTX 1070 (Gygabyte G1 1070 8Gb Rev 1.0)
>
> RAM : 16 Gb (Overclocked to 3200 MHz)
>
> STORAGE :
>
> / on a M.2
>
> /home on a Old Hard drive

output of " lspci -k | grep -EA3 '3D|Display|VGA' " :

```
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

top revealed that Xorg and nv_queue where very ressource greedy after installing nvidia driver.

**I tried (with no effect) :**

- switching distro : pop os (with preinstalled nvidia driver), manjaro, debian, linux mint
- installing driver using different method : (with the .run, using graphical-driver ppa,ubuntu driver manager)
- installing different driver ( 340 - 390 - 435 - 440 )
- Changing monitor frequency both in nvidia-setting and ubuntu display settings
- Flashing another firmware into my graphics card (with windows)
- Changing kernel version
- removing nouveau
- disabling/enabling :

  - Sync to VBlank
  - Allow Flipping
  - Force Full Composition Pipeline
  - nvidia "Timer" : Thermal monitor, powerMinimizer monitor, Memory Used
  - pusle audio service

I tried Windows 10 with the latest nvidia driver and it works well. So the question is what can I do to spot the source of the issue (excluding the fact that the driver is proprietary) ?. Thanks your help

Comment: if you're using the latest kernel, I'd suggest you boot into an earlier version

Comment: @rubaiat Thanks for the suggestion rubaiat. I tried with the 4.15 kernel and the issue remain but it seems a bit more fluid.